# How do I find the exact location of a file in python with pygame?

Tags: python, file, directory, pygame

I need to have the exact directory of an image for a game I'm making in python with pygame. I know what the folder and file are called, but not where my user puts it. Please help, I won't be able to continue my project without you guys :(
The file i'm trying to find is in the same folder as the .py and is a .bmp

Comment: So you're basically trying to find the directory where the source code of a module is stored?

Comment: No, i'm trying to find the directory of a file. example: C:\Users\someuser\Dekstop\examplefolder\filethatneedsdirectory.bmp

Comment: But can that directory be any directory at all and you have no further information than it contains that file? Tough luck then, but from the last sentence of your question, it seems that the directory you want is *also* the directory containing some Python source file which you imported.

Comment: Yes it can be any directory where the user put the folder really, and regarding the last part it is a python program I made in a folder with all the resources (images, saves and music). I need to know the directory for them to be able to load the images and music to make the game actually make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the path relative to where your python module is stored in the file system (as you seemed to indicate) you can use the following to calculate the abs path and then build up an appropriate path from there.

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

NOTE: Change print for python2.7

Use `os.path.join` to build up the new path.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) documentation page, especially at `os.path.abspath`.